# Resulting pdf of multiple trials

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If I have a pdf, $f_0(x)$, from which I sample $n$ times, what is the resulting pdf, $f_n(x)$, which tells me the relative likelihood to take a given value at least once?

For example, if there's some $x'$ for which $f_0(x')dx\sim0.01$ and I draw 100 times, I'd expect this resulting pdf to have $f_{100}(x')dx\sim1.0$.

I'm interested specifically in the exponential distribution, though a general response would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^N$ is a collection of $n$, independent, identically distributed random variables, each drawn from a distribution with probability density function $f_X$ (note the change of notation, you call this $f_0$). The probability that any one of the $X_n$ values is in a specified range is given by

$$
P_X(a,b) = \Pr[a<X_n<b] = \int_a^bf_X(x)dx\tag{1}
$$

Now, you want to know what is the probability that at least one of the $X_n$ is in that range. That case is complimentary to the case where NONE of the $X_n$ are in that range, so that
$$
\Pr\left[\text{at least one } X_n\in(a,b)\right] = 1 - \Pr\left[\text{none of } X_n\in(a,b)\right]\tag{2}
$$

Now, whether a given $X_n$ is between some bounds $(a,b)$ is an independent Bernoulli trial with probability given by $(1)$ above, and since we have a collection of them, we know this results in the binomial distribution. The probability of getting exactly $K$ of your $N$ variables to fall in that range is given by the binomial probability mass function:
$$
\Pr\left[\text{exactly $K$ of the } X_n\in(a,b)\right]=f(K,N,P_X) = {N\choose K}P_X^K(1-P_X)^{N-K}\tag{3}
$$

Inserting that in $(2)$ gives
$$
\Pr\left[\text{at least one } X_n\in(a,b)\right] = 1 - f(0,N,P_X) =
1-(1-P_X)^{N}
$$
This is your final answer. Note that this isn't really a probability density function, but rather, a probability of the outcome of interest. There is no density or mass to speak of when you're only interested in one outcome, which is "one or more successes". In general, $(3)$ is the probability mass function for the outcome "exactly $K$ successes".

Note then that in your example of a certain range having probability of $1\%$, if we draw $100$ times, the above formula tells you that the probability of hitting at least one out of the hundred is 
$$
1-(1-0.01)^{100}=1-0.99^{100}\approx 1-0.366=0.634=63.4\%,
$$
which is smaller than you thought it would be. This makes for interesting psychology in casinos too; people think that if they bet with $1\%$ chance of winning $100$ times, they are practically guaranteed to win at least once, when in fact, the chances of winning at least once are closer to a coin toss than they are to a sure thing. In this scenario, it takes $298$ trials to get to $95\%$, $458$ trials to get to $99\%$, and $683$ trials to get to $99.9\%$

Comment: Thanks.  I appreciate the worked example.  I had arrived at the answer through basic reasoning, but was confused that it's not a pdf.